# How import toPromise into component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I use *Angular 2.0* in *ASP.NET* project and stuck with error of importing *rxjs* into component to use in `this.http.get`/`this.http.post`.

Angular settings:

```
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",

    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6"
```

On component:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

In function I try to get data from `http.get` requet and handle responce with `toPromise`:

```
    getData(): Promise<IToDo[]> {
        return this.http.get('app/shared/todos.json')
            .toPromise() // <- ERROR
            .then(res => res.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
```

I guess `toPromise()` not imported correct. But I check in `node_modules` all forders exist and `toPromise.d.ts`, `toPromise.js`, `toPromise.js.map` available.

ERROR:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error TS2339 Property 'toPromise' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'. TypeScript Virtual Projects C:\Users\max\Desktop\LocalAccountsApp-master\LocalAccountsApp\app\home\GL\gl.service.ts 39 Active
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? what is the error?

Comment: Do you have `import './rxjs-operators';` in your root component?

Comment: No I have not such import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generally caused by the latest versions. The solution to this will be using RC-4 or RC-5 release along with RX-JS. You can have a generic
`import 'rxjs/Rx'`;